# understand what IDE Eclipse do when building project (maven command ?)

Tags: eclipse, maven, build

i try to understand excactly what Eclipse IDE do as maven goal when building project.

In fact, i don't undersand the following sequence :

1/ in line command, i do : mvn clean
2/ ok, target folder is empty
3/ in Eclipse, i force a class not to compile with a bad keyword
4/ as i save the file, Eclipse build automatically
5/ i am really surprised to see that target folder with files *.class created !

of course, application fails to start.
But, i'd like to understand why *.class have been created, as compile fails !

so :

A) what exactly Eclipse do in background when rebuilding (maven goal?) and where can we see it in IDE configuration ?
B) why *.class are created as compil failed ?

Comment: Eclipse has its own incremental Java compiler. By defaults, on save `.java` files will be compiled into the output folder. Compiler settings: _Project > Properties: Java Compiler_. In _Java Compiler > Error/Warnings_ there is a checkbox at the bottom _Treat above errors like fatal compiler errors_ that is disable by default to create `.class` files even if there are compile errors.

Comment: absolutly exact! building by IDE seems to make similary action as maven goal process-classes